# is Video tag in html a POST request or GET request?

Tags: python, html

I  am iusing  in my html. I am trying to handle the request on server side using python BaseHTTPServer. I want to figure out how the request from video tag looks like???

Answer (score 1):

It will be a simple GET request, just like any other resource embedded in an HTML document.

If you really want to examine exactly what browsers send, then use something like Charles or the Net tab of Firebug.

Comment: "Live HTTP Headers" is another tool that works for figuring out stuff like this.

Comment: Thank you so much guys.. the tools were helpful and it seems that Video tag is no deifferent than img tag and its a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

POST is usually reserved for form submissions because you are POSTing form information to the server. In this case you are just GETing the contents of a `<video>` source.